# Find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $e^{x^7-8x}$ at $(-1,e^7)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $g(x)=e^{x^7-8x}$ at $(-1,e^7)$

---

$Solution:$

The value of the slope of the tangent line to $g(x)$ at the point $(-1,e^7)$ is $g'(-1)$, so lets calculate that.

$g'(x)=e^{x^7-8x}(x^7-8x)'=e^{x^7-8x}(7x^6-8)$

$\rightarrow g'(-1)=e^{(-1)^7-8(-1)}(7(-1)^6-8)=e^{7}(-1)=-e^7$

So we know that $y=-e^7x+b$. Let's plug in the given point to solve for $b$.

$e^7=-e^7(-1)+b$

$\rightarrow b=0$

Thus our equation is $y=-e^7x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done! Your equation is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1333295)

Comment: @AlanMuniz: Exactly how do you propose one should handle a solution-verification problem? This answer looks perfectly fine to me and does what the OP asked, plus it got two upvotes.